# How to override tailwindCSS with our own CSS?

Tags: html, css

For example, if I only want some specific classes to use from it and disable everything else to be able to use my own CSS properties only, how do we do that?

Comment: Eh? Use another class names? Delete rules in CSS sheet?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you want to do btw @pavel answer is correct

Comment: I was implementing navigation for mobile with tailwindcss but for rest of the stuff, I don't need tailwind css.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Nah no need now. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add Internal style code by declaring your own class names. You could also add `!important` to the css properties to ensure you overwrite the external style sheet. For example, if there is a footer class and you want to change it's position, you could use `position: absolute !important;`.

PS: It is not preferred to use a css framework for only one element in your website.

Comment: thanks. I just implemented CSS framework fully instead.

Comment: Good to know it's helpful. Would you mind to mark it as the answer if it helped you? This might be helpful for future visitors. Thank you.